# Remove the white border bottom of Header View Section in Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I removed the separator style in Storyboard to none but still a 1px white border at the bottom of the header view is showing.
I tried to set the separator style on viewdidload to none, and tried with some extension that were to remove the sub-views but that still did not work.

I use a cell to dequeue in my header view and set a height for it.
Here is my code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return 1
        case 1:
            return 1
        case 2:
            return 1
        case 3:
            return 1
        case 4:
            return 1
        case 5:
            return 1
        case 6:
            return 1
        default:
            return 1
        }
    }

    // MARK: - View For Header

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        switch section {
        case 2:

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductHeaderTableViewCell") as! NewProductHeaderTableViewCell
            tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Produktet e reja"
            return cell
        case 3:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductHeaderTableViewCell") as! NewProductHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Top Produktet"
            return cell
        case 4:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductHeaderTableViewCell") as! NewProductHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Me te shiturat"
            return cell
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Height For Header

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch section {
        case 2:
            return 46.0
        case 3:
            return 46.0
        case 4:
            return 46.0
        default:
            return 0.1
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    // MARK: - Height For Row

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return 90
        case 1:
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        case 2:
            return 177
        case 3:
            return 177
        case 4:
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        case 5:
            return 90
        case 6:
            return 90
        default:
            return 90
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Cell For Row

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryTableViewCell
            return cell
        case 1:
            return UITableViewCell()
        case 2:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewProductTableViewCell
            return cell
        case 3:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewProductTableViewCell
            return cell
        case 4:
            return UITableViewCell()
        case 5:
            return UITableViewCell()
        case 6:
            return UITableViewCell()
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: This might not fix your problem but you can always change the background color to that same gray color. I know it’s the answer you want but just an alternative until you find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is UIEdgeInsets.zero but still doe snot work

Answer (score 0):

try with This

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    switch section {
    case 2:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductHeaderTableViewCell") as! NewProductHeaderTableViewCell
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Produktet e reja"
        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductHeaderTableViewCell") as! NewProductHeaderTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Top Produktet"
        return cell
    case 4:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewProductHeaderTableViewCell") as! NewProductHeaderTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Me te shiturat"
        return cell
    default:
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }
}
```